# How to pass data to reference wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, reference-wrapper

Consider following piece of code:

```
//option no 1
struct foo{
    foo(baz &b) : _b(b){}

    std::reference_wrapper<baz> _b;
};

//option no 2
struct bar{
    bar(std::reference_wrapper<baz> b) : _b(b){}

    std::reference_wrapper<baz> _b;
};
```

I am wondering if there are any practical differences between initializing `foo` and `bar`. If so, what are the pros and cons of each solution and which should be preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least difference with types with conversion operator:

```
struct tobaz
{
    operator baz&() const { static baz b; return b; }
};
```

Then

```
foo{tobaz()}; // Compile
bar{tobaz()}; // Won't compile
```

As only one user conversion can take place.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad025229e90cb6ad)

Error would happen the other side for struct with `operator std::reference_wrapper<baz>()`.